# The command clickhouse-backup create provides no metadata folder and an empty shadow folder

Tags: clickhouse

I have a clickhouse database called "clickhouse_database" and a table called "actions" which has some data in it which I want to take a backup of.

Running the command "sudo clickhouse-backup create" gives me this response:

```
c/camel/source/project/clickhouse-backup$ sudo clickhouse-backup create
2021/01/08 00:27:09 Create backup '2021-01-07T23-27-09'
2021/01/08 00:27:09 Freeze `clickhouse_database`.`actions`
2021/01/08 00:27:09 Skip `system`.`asynchronous_metric_log`
2021/01/08 00:27:09 Skip `system`.`metric_log`
2021/01/08 00:27:09 Skip `system`.`part_log`
2021/01/08 00:27:09 Skip `system`.`query_log`
2021/01/08 00:27:09 Skip `system`.`trace_log`
2021/01/08 00:27:09 Copy metadata
2021/01/08 00:27:09   Done.
2021/01/08 00:27:09 Move shadow
2021/01/08 00:27:09 open /var/lib/clickhouse/shadow: no such file or directory
```

I can see that in the backup directory "/var/lib/clickhouse/backup" is created with a timestamp as name which is expected:

```
$ ls
2021-01-06T19-04-12  2021-01-07T23-24-24  2021-01-07T23-27-09
```

Inside one of these directories I'd expect that there is a shadow and a metadata directory but what I see is that there's only a shadow directory which is empty:

```
/2021-01-07T23-27-09$ ls
shadow
```

**What am I missing here?**

Note:

I'm using this as a guide to use the clickhouse-backup tool:
https://altinity.com/blog/introduction-to-clickhouse-backups-and-clickhouse-backup

Comment: if you execute SQL command `alter table clickhouse_database.actions freeze` , do you see a new folder in `/var/lib/clickhouse/shadow` ?

Comment: @DennyCrane No. In "/var/lib/clickhouse/" there's only the backup folder.

Comment: OK. But where is your CH data folder?

Comment: @DennyCrane I have a kubernetes cluster where I have the clickhouse operator running which created a pod. Inside that pod I created "clickhouse_database". I'm connected to that instance via Tabix.io and from there I've created the table "actions" and inserted data with sql commands. I'm not sure if that answered your question or not, but I don't seem to have a local folder for my data this way.

Comment: clickhouse-backup does not support kubernetes clusters & does not support CH 20.10+

Comment: Lots of appreciation for your responses. May I ask if you know of a possible solution of taking backup of CH databases inside a k8s clusters? 
You may answer here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65636534/backup-of-a-clickhouse-db-inside-a-k8s-cluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be located inside the given pod before

```
clickhouse-backup create
```

will work.

You can get a shell into the pod with the command

```
kubectl exec --stdin --tty <podname> -- /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this fight with clickhouse-backup too.

This is what I had to do:

1. Create /var/lib/clickhouse/shadow
2. `chown clickhouse:clickhouse /var/lib/clickhouse/shadow`
3. `chown clickhouse:clickhouse /var/lib/clickhouse/store/backup`
4. `su clickhouse`
5. ^ make sure you run the backup process as the clickhouse user (root doesn't work for me ?!)

And then for me, the backups that clickhouse-backup creates are actually empty directories(see /var/lib/clickhouse/store/backup/[time stamp of backup]/shadow)

This is because for some reason the backup process moves *all* the backup files to /var/lib/clickhouse/shadow

I then had to

4. `mv /var/lib/clickhouse/shadow/* /var/lib/clickhouse/store/backup/[your backup timestamp]/shadow/`

EDIT: Actual solution: I was using an old version of the application. Use the latest and you should be OK. See: https://github.com/AlexAkulov/clickhouse-backup/releases